How do I make a chord in the beginning that I don't want to repeat?
I'm currently working on my second piece ever on Noteflight and I'm trying to add a guitar chord in the beginning, with a repeat soon after, but I don't want the chord to repeat. I've tried searching for things like this before, but found no good answers. If you want to hear the piece to maybe see what I'm looking for and why, here's the link: (https://www.noteflight.com/scores/view/ed3719ccce6a99cd976b8f0d6bfdfe2d94721824). I think you'll agree with me that the chord itself doesn't need to repeat. Keep in mind while I am asking specifically about the chord in the first measure, I have other places where I would like to fix this as well. I'll mark the measures where I need help with down brackets (I have no idea what functional purpose brackets serve).

I don't understand the question. There are no chords in the guitar part (do you mean the one in the bass part?), and I don't see any repeats. Please clarify.

I'm so sorry, I did some work on it at home and I guess it didn't update, but I'll try to put the chords in now

It should be good now; at the very least it's working for me.

It looks the same to me, with the possible exception of some triads at the end of the bass part. I don't remember those from before. But still no guitar chord(s) at the beginning. Regardless, it would be best to embed an image in the post itself rather than providing a link.

I have always thought of repeat marks as a type of shorthand.  If we did not have them we would simply write out the music a second time.
If I have understood your score correctly you have bars 1,2 and 3;  then you want to repeat bar one with some differences, repeat bar 2 and then its a new bar because its the second time.  So the only bar that is actually repeated is bar 2.  Is that correct?
So why bother with the repeat marks?  Surely everything would be much clearer if you just wrote out all the bars.

It seems to me that you want to repeat 3 measures, but 2 of them are different in each repetition:

the strummed guitar chord is only in the first repetition
the last measure is also different (volta 1 and volta 2)

There isn't really a standard notation for what you want to achieve. You could use smaller note heads for the strummed chord, and a written note (e.g. play in the first repetition only).
Unless you are very short of space for some reason, I suggest not to use repetition notation in this case. It will be difficult to read.
